# How can I make the thread wait between 2 methods

Tags: android, database, multithreading, android-room

I have this function- inserting data to Room database in android app:

public void insertInfoToDB() {

```
final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

            int medId = db.medicationsDao().getMedicationIdByName(medName);

            //insert data to medications table
            MedicationsTable medication = new MedicationsTable(medId, medName, amountDosageMg, remindersAmountPerDay);
            db.medicationsDao().insert(medication);

            //insert data to reminders table
            RemindersTable reminder;
            for (int i = 0; i < selectedDaysSet.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < allReminderTimes.size(); j++) {
                    reminder = new RemindersTable(allReminderTimes.get(j).getHour(),
                            allReminderTimes.get(j).getMinutes(), allReminderTimes.get(j).getDoses()
                            , selectedDaysSet.get(i), medication.getId());
                    db.medicationsDao().insertReminder(reminder);

                    createNotification(reminder.getId(), allReminderTimes.get(j).getHour(),
                            allReminderTimes.get(j).getMinutes(), allReminderTimes.get(j).getDoses(),
                            selectedDaysSet.get(i));
                }
            }
```

While the data is inserted to db, the primary key (autoGenerated) id is 0 and I need to make something with the key right after.
So I need to "hold" or something between "db.medicationsDao().insertReminder(reminder);" and "createNotification" (called right after) so that the thread will finish the inserting to the database before I call createNotification.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did I correctly understood, `insertReminder` is asynchronous method?

Comment: i think you can use delay like 100 ms and you can check your id value if id value greater than 0. You will know insert operation successfull. Then you can create notification. You have to search thread sleep, delay.

Comment: certainly you could do that and wait for the primary key from the auto generated id or you could assign the table a GUID--no need to wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **CountDownTimer** class:

```
long waitingTime = 5000; //in milli second
long countDownInteval = 2000;
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(waitingTime, countDownInterval) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            //Write your code here
        }
    };
    countDownTimer.start();
```

---

In this code,

- the onTick(long remained) method will call after each 2 second
- the onFinish() mehtod will call after 5 seconds

Document: [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer)